# Use file dialog to select a folder that contains a specific file type?

Tags: c++, winapi

Our application saves its projects as a folder full of stuff, including the actual project file something.abc

It is a niggle that when loading a project, we have to go into the project folder and find the project file. I know there are folder-selection OS dialogs but I only want it to work if it can see the file exists inside the folder.

I'm sure I saw this done but I've no idea how... we're using Qt but answers for that or natively for Windows are welcome. The one thing is I want to use the native OS dialogs not build my own from scratch.

Answer (score 6):

The Win32 `SHBrowseForFolder()` and `IFileOpenDialog` APIs both allow the user to select a folder.

Both APIs allow you to react to dialog events, like changes to the current folder selection, validation of the current selection, etc.  `SHBrowseForFolder()` has a callback function, and `IFileOpenDialog` has an `IFileDialogEvents` sink interface.

Such a callback/sink can check whether the currently selected folder has a given file type, and then block or allow the dialog from returning that result to the caller.

### `SHBrowseForFolder()`

To check for a file type's existence:

- get the folder's filesystem path by passing its absolute PIDL to `SHGetPathFromIDList()`.
- then search that path using `FindFirstFile()` with the desired filename pattern mask.

or

- retrieve an `IShellFolder` interface by passing the folder's absolute PIDL to `SHBindToObject()` (or, on pre-Vista systems, use `SHGetDesktopFolder()` to get the `IShellFolder` of the top-level Desktop shell namespace, then pass the PIDL to its `BindToObject()` method).
- then use the `IShellFolder::EnumObjects()` method to get its `IEnumIDList` interface.
- then enumerate the relative PIDLs of the files, using the parent folder's `IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf()` method to look for a file matching the desired filename pattern.

To block or allow the dialog from returning success to the caller, the callback function can handle the `BFFM_SELCHANGED` notification to validate the folder as needed and then send the dialog window a `BFFM_ENABLEOK` message with the `lParam` set to zero or non-zero accordingly.

### `IFileOpenDialog`

To check for a file type's existence:

- use the folder's `IShellItem::BindToHandler()` method to retrieve its `IEnumShellItems` interface.
- then enumerate the `IShellItem` interfaces for the files, using the `IShellItem::GetDisplayName()` method to look for a file matching the desired filename pattern.

To block or allow the dialog from returning success to the caller, the sink can implement the `OnFileOk` event to validate the selected folder and return `S_OK` or `S_FALSE` as needed.

Alternatively, the sink can implement the `OnFolderChange` event to enable/disable the dialog's OK button directly (`IFileDialogCustomize::SetControlState()` doesn't work in this case):

- retrieve the dialog's `HWND` by querying the dialog for its `IOleWindow` interface, and then calling its `GetWindow()` method.
- then use the Win32 `GetDlgItem()` function to get the `HWND` of the OK button using the standard `IDOK` control ID.
- then use the Win32 `EnableWindow()` function to enable/disable the button.

Comment: Great - so I know on Windows it is possible, which probably means other WinAPI might wrap it (i.e. .NET) and possibly cross-platform libraries like wxWidgets and Qt. Something to start by search from anyway. Thanks.